# How do I stop my bot from responding to @everyone pings but also respond to @Bot pings in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a bot that responds when I ping it by tagging its ID but it also responds to @everyone pings. How do I filter those out? I've tried using an if statement to filter out @everyone and the ID of @everyone but then the bot doesn't respond to normal pings. Here's the current code:

```
@bot.listen('on_message')
async def on_ping(message):
  if bot.user.mentioned_in(message):
    if "<@747577395086884998>" in message.content:
      return
    else:
      channel = message.channel
      embed=discord.Embed(color=0x0fd249)
      file = discord.File("logo.png", filename="image.png")
      embed.set_author(name="Fallen Bot", icon_url="attachment://image.png")
      embed.add_field(name="Hi! I'm Fallen Bot!", value=f"My prefix is, `{bot.command_prefix}` and you can use `{bot.command_prefix}help` for help!", inline=False)
      await channel.send(file=file, embed=embed)
```

I'm using the commands extension from the rewrite. The first block of the code is the filter for @everyone and the second part, below the `else` statement is the response to a ping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`message.mention_everyone`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mention_everyone) attribute to filter out @everyone and @here-pings like so:

```py
@bot.listen('on_message')
async def on_ping(message):
    if message.mention_everyone:
        return
    else:
        # this is a real ping, do your thing
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the bot was mentioned in the message, instead of check if it wasn't an everyone ping

```py
if "<!@100>" in message.content: # 100 is the bots id, change it to yours
    # handle the ping here
```

Comment: This won't make the bot respond to an @Bot role ping, however

Comment: @LukasThaler True, I'm not sure how to just exclude the @ everyone ping though